# How to update field value in a Go template

Tags: templates, go, struct

I have the following case, where I am passing a struct containing a map to a template:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var fns = template.FuncMap{
    "plus1": func(x int) int {
        return x + 1
    },
}

type codec struct {
    Names map[string]string
    Count int
}

func main() {
    a := map[string]string{"one": "1",
        "two":   "2",
        "three": "3"}

    t := template.Must(template.New("abc").Funcs(fns).Parse(`{{$l := len .Names}}{{range $k, $v := .Names}}{{if ne (plus1 $.Count) $l}}{{$k}} {{$v}} {{end}}{{end}}.`))

    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, codec{a, 0})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

I would like to increment the `Count` field of `codec` so that I can know how many items of the map I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define a method on your struct:

```
type codec struct {
    Names map[string]string
    Count int
}

func (c *codec) IncAndGet() int {
    c.Count++
    return c.Count
}
```

Calling it from a template:

```
c := &codec{Count: 2}
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{.IncAndGet}} {{.IncAndGet}}`))
t.Execute(os.Stdout, c)
```

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/V25PyArkSn)</kbd>):

```
3 4
```

Note that for this to work, the method needs a pointer receiver (`func (c *codec) IncAndGet()`) and you have to pass a pointer to `Template.Execute()` (`c` is a pointer in our example: `c := &codec{Count: 2}`).

If you don't want any result just counting, define it to have a `string` return type and return the empty `string` `""`:

```
func (c *codec) Inc() string {
    c.Count++
    return ""
}
```

Comment: This works well, but too bad the method has to return something. I only really wanted the counter effect. I ened up running the method as an empty if statement to get around it.

Comment: @Lars You can define the method to return `string`, and simply return `""` so it won't have any output.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the `plus1` function a closure that acts directly on the value of the `codec`:

```
// first create a codec instance
c := codec {a, 0}

// now define the function as a closure with a reference to c
fns := template.FuncMap{
  "plus1": func() int {
      c.Count++
      return c.Count
   },
}

// now we don't need to pass anything to it in the template
t := template.Must(template.New("abc").Funcs(fns).Parse(`{{$l := len .Names}}{{range $k, $v := .Names}}{{if ne (plus1) $l}}{{$k}} {{$v}} {{end}}{{end}}.`))
```

The output was:

```
one 1 three 3
```

which I'm guessing is what you were aiming for? And the value is retained in `c` at the end of execution.

Comment: This works too, but the accepted answer ended up fitting better with the rest of my code.

Comment: @Lars I agree it's more elegant